# Google Maps Street View for a specific date (different years)

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-street-view

I am trying to find a way to load the Google Maps Street View for a specific location for different years. For example, on google maps it lets you go back as far as 2007. How can I make Google load the map from another year instead of the current year using google API in python?
I did not find any commend in Google API document. Can you help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this feature is not available in the Street View API.

However,this feature has been requested in the issue tracker. Kindly star this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35826204) to get automatic notifications if there are updates on this topic. You may also share your use case by adding a comment to the feature request.